Downspout positioning at gutter corners
Downspouts positioned at gutter corners at my house are all offset from the corners.

There are no other downspouts at either end of the gutters away from this corner. I assume (haven't measured yet) that the gutter sections should slope (red arrows) towards the downspout (yellow oval).

With such slopes the area shaded in red must be collecting debris and have standing water for prolonged periods of time.
Shouldn't the downspout be positioned right at the gutter corner?
Alternatively, should the shaded area of the gutter be sloped towards the downspout as well? (Which means one of the gutters would be bent at the spot where downspout is.)

Flow from the other leg will wash debris in the corner back toward the downspout. It isn't perfect, but it's common and mostly des the job. Unless you have direct evidence of a problem I wouldn't worry about it.

Ideally, the gutter would be sloped to drain toward the downspout.  In your case, if you have stagnation in the corner, it would be possible to add a new downspout in the "front" gutter, connecting to the section of downspout fastened to the house.  You'd need an A-B transition elbow.
